# only on instance of Thread is created per Object Instance

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class AsyncCommand {
    public int i=1;
    public Object lock=new Object();

    public void execute() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(true){
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        try {
                            if(i%2 ==0){
                                lock.wait();
                            }

                            System.out.println(i);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            i++;
                            lock.notify();

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }


            }
        });
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        try {
                            if(i%2 !=0){
                                lock.wait();
                            }
                            System.out.println(i);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            i++;
                            lock.notify();

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }



            }
        });
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsyncCommand a=new AsyncCommand();
    //AsyncCommand a1=new AsyncCommand();
    a.execute();
    a.execute();
    a.execute();
    //a1.execute();
    //a1.execute();
}
```

}

actual output:
1
2
3
4
5
.
expected output:
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
.
.

why Threads are created only for the first call of execute() .after that no threads are created. For every call of execute method Two new threads should be created                                                          .

Answer (score 1):

Multiple threads **are** being created. But they all use the same `i` because there's only one `AsyncCommand` instance and `i` is an instance variable. So you only see the value ascending.

You can tell multiple threads are running by changing

```
System.out.println(i);
```

to

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + i);
```

in both places you output `i`. Then you'll see

```
Thread-0: 1
Thread-5: 2
Thread-4: 3
Thread-3: 4
Thread-2: 5
Thread-1: 6
Thread-2: 7
...
```

...or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually multiple threads are created. But the problem is, you used same instance's variable 'i' in each created thread.

So while one thread is in waiting state, the other thread increments value of 'i'. So, if you want the desired result, create and use new instance for AsyncCommand class for each execute() call.

Test.java

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       AsyncCommand a1=new AsyncCommand();
       AsyncCommand a2=new AsyncCommand();
       AsyncCommand a3=new AsyncCommand();
       a1.execute();
       a2.execute();
       a3.execute();
   }
```